# How do I put the dragged item at the screen position where it was left?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

In this drag and drop, I'd like to put the dragged HTML element exactly where it was left by the mouse but currently it's putting the control in the top most left. I'm putting the element in the drop target div by a [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), I have no code to show yet because  I have no idea how to do that yet, how to get the coordinates in the end of the drag operation and insert the HTML element in this very same coordinates in the final drag div.

Example with images. So let's say I drag the HTML element to this position:

[image]

the HTML should stay there rather go to left top most:

[image]

my code look like this:

```
<style>
.toolbox {
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    border: solid 3px #ccc;
    margin: 10px;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.edit {
    width: 140px;
}

.form {
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    border: solid 3px red;
}

.drop-targets {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    //justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.drag-over {
    border: dashed 3px red;
}
</style>

<div class="drop-targets">
    <div id="controls" class="toolbox">
        <input type="button" value="Button 1" id="button1" draggable="true" class="control"> <br>
        <input type="text" value="Edit 1" class="edit" draggable="true" class="control">
    </div>
    <div id="panel" class="form"></div>
</div>

<script>
const item = document.querySelector('.control');

item.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);

function dragStart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
    setTimeout(() => {
        e.target.classList.add('hide');
    }, 0);
}

const box = document.querySelector('#panel');
box.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
box.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
box.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
box.addEventListener('drop', drop);

function dragEnter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.classList.add('drag-over');
}

function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.classList.add('drag-over');
}

function dragLeave(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('drag-over');
}

function drop(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('drag-over');

    const id = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    const draggable = document.getElementById(id);

    e.target.appendChild(draggable);

    draggable.classList.remove('hide');
}

</script>
```

Comment: Add `position: relative` to the drop zone container and `position: absolute` to the dragged element. In this case, dragged element can be positioned at specific location but will still be limited by drop zone area. Also, you probably don't want to add `display: flex` to your drop zone because `flex` tries to rearrange its children. If it doesn't work right away, you may need to add one more event, e.g. `mousemove` to track coordinates.

Comment: html drag and drop api is a disaster. I rarely see someone use it tho.

Comment: thanks for your input, I'll be using a library to take of the javascript part for me

Comment: @YvesNg I was just getting start so i went using that API. I'm tring out react dnd library now, seems a better approach

Answer (score 2):

Get the coordinates of the element dropped relative to the parent like so:

```js
var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
const coordinates = [e.pageX - rect.left, e.pageY - rect.top];
```

Set the draggable element's position to `absolute`, and set the corresponding `left` and `top` attributes.

Example:

```js
const item = document.querySelector('.control');

item.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);

function dragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
  setTimeout(() => {
    e.target.classList.add('hide');
  }, 0);
}

const box = document.querySelector('#panel');
box.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
box.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
box.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
box.addEventListener('drop', drop);

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('drag-over');
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('drag-over');
}

function dragLeave(e) {
  e.target.classList.remove('drag-over');
}

function drop(e) {
  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const coordinates = [e.pageX - rect.left, e.pageY - rect.top];
  e.target.classList.remove('drag-over');

  const id = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  const draggable = document.getElementById(id);

  e.target.appendChild(draggable);
  draggable.style.position = "absolute";
  draggable.style.left = coordinates[0] + "px";
  draggable.style.top = coordinates[1] + "px";
  draggable.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

```css
#panel {
  position: relative;
}

.toolbox {
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid 3px #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.edit {
  width: 140px;
}

.form {
  height: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid 3px red;
}

.drop-targets {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  //justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.drag-over {
  border: dashed 3px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-targets">
  <div id="controls" class="toolbox">
    <input type="button" value="Button 1" id="button1" draggable="true" class="control"> <br>
    <input type="text" value="Edit 1" class="edit" draggable="true" class="control">
  </div>
  <div id="panel" class="form"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. The control doesn't stay exactly where it was left. There are areas where it jumps from say middle to bottom or top.